# Globally set default rendering for None

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it possible to set different rendering for `None` globally or per template? So I tell `Django` to render all `None` as `-` for example.

There are pages like `profile` where we have tens of attributes and this would be slightly better than taking care of every possible None or rewriting every attribute from:

```
{{ user.userprofile.attribute }}
```

To

```
{% firstof user.userprofile.attribute "-" %}
```

or

```
{{ user.userprofile.attribute|default:"-" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default setting in `settings.py` in `TEMPLATES`.

**Solution**:

```
if DEBUG:
    TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['string_if_invalid'] = '-' # or any value
```

You can do this for as many backends you have or mention it directly in `TEMPLATES.OPTIONS` dict.

The reason I put if `DEBUG` is set, is because of [how invalid template variables are handled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables). Read the note in the end in the link for the reference.

Comment: This doesn't work. It works for undefined variables but not for None values.